# Why won't my text posts save, it worked before?

Tags: django, django-views

My text posts were working before adding a notification feature but now they aren't, I have a debug print but instead of seeing the post object, I'm seeing the user that posted it. I haven't changed anything other than getting the post id,  `timesince` and the notify function, I've used the exact same method with my picture and video posts and they work fine, so it doesn't make sense to me. I've got a debug print in the notification function to make sure the post type and id have been passed correctly and those indeed show the id and type

views.py

```
@login_required()
def text_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TextPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            t_post = form.save(commit=False)
            t_post.author = request.user
            t_post.save()

            id = t_post.id
            time = timesince
            print(t_post) # t_post shows the user instead of the post

            followers = list(request.user.followers.all())
            notify(followers,
            request.user,
            f"{request.user.username} posted {time}",
            id,
            'text'
            )
            print(t_post)
            #redirect to last page
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = TextPostForm()
        post_type = 'text'
        return render(request, 'create_post.html', {'form': form, 'post_type': post_type})
```

forms.py

```
class TextPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TextPost
        fields = ('description','privacy', 'categories')
```

Comment: Post the source code for your `TextPostForm` please.

Comment: Added the form. Sorry about that

Comment: All good. Everything looks ok to me, the symptom you are having does not make much sense. Are you sure you are not seeing the output of a different `print` statement, somewhere else in your code? Try changing your debugging line to something like `print("Debug line #1234", type(t_post), t_post)`...

Comment: Something must be causing inconsistency because now it's showing the object after changing the debug print as you suggested. This doesn't make much sense....

Comment: It might be a stale compiled file. Try deleting any `__pycache__`, `*.pyc`, `*.pyo` etc files before testing it again.

Comment: Including the inner project folder? Where settings.py is?

Comment: I would delete everything to make sure. They will automatically be regenerated anyway.

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll remember the possibility of a stale ```__pychache__```, thank you. If you've got some advanced django docs or tutorials, please let me know so I can learn more. I've been teaching myself for a while and really need to learn more. Making a social media site is taking alot of learning and the more resources the better! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, the ones I would recommend have probably been obsoleted by now. I'd suggest you to ask this question on somewhere like reddit.com/r/django/ or /r/python/ where people might have _fresher_ ideas.

Comment: Okay thank you, I've followed alot of tutorials with deprecated methods and have learned how to fix them lol. Anything you can provide would help; I'll take your advice and hit that page, thank you again!

Comment: I would stick to the official Django documentation for up-to-date information. For starting out Two Scoops of Django is a good book but note that the last update of the book is for Django 1.11, which is ancient today.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it, thank you.